# Anyway to run grunt task run with arguments

Tags: gruntjs

Currently I do like below to run a grunt task

```
grunt somTask:opt --ignore
```

I would like to call the same through JS and doing the below

```
grunt.task.run('someTask:opt --ignore');
```

But it is failed saying property not found in options. But would like to know if there is a possibility for this.